# Does my printheads need cleaning / changing?

Tags: printing, printer, inkjet-printer

I've just put new ink in my old printer that wasn't printing well. This didn't solve the problem. I'm thinking I may have to clean or change the printheads but I'm not sure this will solve the problem.

The printer is an HP OfficeJet Pro L7480 All-In-One.

Here's an image of a printed versus the original image:
[image]